# My PHP Script Running fine in XAMPP local server but throwing 500 error in BlueHost Server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I am trying to add some record into database using php. I am passing the data using jquery ajax post request.
Here is my php code that is posting the record to the database

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'db.php';
$data=$_POST['data'];

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);

foreach($data as $d){

    $lname=$d['last'];

    $fname=$d['first'];

    $email=$d['email'];

    $classid=$_SESSION['classid'];

    $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO  `Students` (LastName,FirstName,Email,classid,profile,confirmation)

    VALUES (:LastName,:FirstName,:Email,:classid,:profile,:confirmation)');

    //$records->bindParam(':LastName',$lname);

    //$records->bindParam(':FirstName',$fname);

    //$records->bindParam(':Email',$email);

    //$url=addcslashes('studentimg/dimg.png',"/");
$urs='test';
    //$records->bindParam(':profile',$url);

    //$records->bindParam(':classid',$classid);

    $confirmation=randomCode();

    //$records->bindParam(':confirmation',$confirmation);

    $link="www.example.com/studentpwdchange?code=$confirmation";
    echo $link;
    $records->debugDumpParams();
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
        "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
    mail($email,"You have been added to my class","Hello You have been added to my class. Go to $link",$headers);

        $params = array(
        ':LastName' => $lname,
        ':FirstName' => $fname,
        ':Email' => $email,
        ':profile' => $link,
        ':classid' => $classid,
        ':confirmation' => $confirmation
    );
var_dump($params);
   $records->execute($params);

}



echo 'success';



function randomCode() {

    $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';

    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array

    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache

    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {

        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);

        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];

    }

    return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string

}
```

I am passing the data using jquery in the following way

```
$("#stsubmit").on('click',function(){
    var data=[];
    var first=$("#first_name").val();
    var last=$("#last_name").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();
    var std={"first":first,"last":last,"email":email};
    data.push(std);
    for(i=2;i<=counter;i++)
    {
        var fn=$("#first_name"+i).val();
        var ln=$("#last_name"+i).val();
        var em=$("#email"+i).val();
        var s={"first":fn,"last":ln,"email":em};
        data.push(s);
    }
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'tryaddstudent.php',
        data: {'data':jsonString},
        type: 'POST',
        error: function() {
            console.log('Error');
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            //window.location.href = "standings";
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried many ways and consulted man other answers in stackoverflow. Nothing helped.
In console I am getting the following type message

```
[Object]
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://example.com/UML2/production/tryaddstudent.php 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.min.js:4ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ addStudents:270dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
addStudents:279 500
addStudents:280 www.example.com/studentpwdchange?code=agAb2lMQSQL: [153] INSERT INTO  `Students` (LastName,FirstName,Email,classid,profile,confirmation)

    VALUES (:LastName,:FirstName,:Email,:classid,:profile,:confirmation)
Params:  0
array(6) {
  [":LastName"]=>
  string(5) "Islam"
  [":FirstName"]=>
  string(10) "Md Johirul"
  [":Email"]=>
  string(19) "johirbuet@gmail.com"
  [":profile"]=>
  string(47) "www.example.com/studentpwdchange?code=agAb2lMQ"
  [":classid"]=>
  string(8) "o4xu1vPb"
  [":confirmation"]=>
  string(8) "agAb2lMQ"
}

addStudents:281 Internal Server Error
```

Can anyone please help me to figure it out. I don't know what is happening

Comment: Check the server's log to see why the PHP script is getting an error.

Comment: How can i check server log?

Comment: Looks like a database error, which is probably just a configuration issue. Can't say for sure, need more info

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam I don't know. I'll bet BlueHost can tell you.